# Can I not access my xsl:variable this way when I'm outputting plain text

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm doing an xslt transform that generates a sql statement for me. The way I'm using below is not working. Is there a way?

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="@att_val1" />

select $var1.* from $var1

</xsl:template>
```

I know it will work if I do this:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">

select <xsl:value-of select="@att_val1" />.* from <xsl:value-of select="@att_val1" />

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, variable references are recognized in XPath expressions, but not in general template text.  To evaluate an XPath expression and output the result as a text node in the result tree, use `xsl:value-of`, as you already know how to do.  Example:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="@att_val1" />
select <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>.* from <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could build the whole `select` command in one `xsl:value-of` with use of the `concat()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you move to XSLT 3.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates) where you can do e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo" expand-text="yes">select {@att_val1}.* from {@att_val1}</xsl:template>` you will have to use your second option or perhaps a `<xsl:template match="foo"><xsl:value-of select="concat('select ', @att_val1, '.* from ', @att_val1)"/></xsl:template>`, but there is certainly no way in XSLT 1.0 to avoid the use of `xsl:value-of` completely.